# How big is the damage bonus/malus for sensational and pathetic attacks?

Tags: pocket-mortys

I'm trying to decide between unlearning Slam (a 45 power rock-type attack) or Flail (a 65 power neutral attack) on my Unkempt Morty in order to learn Drop Out (a 65 power rock-type attack). How big is the damage bonus/malus for attacking enemies who are weak/strong against attacks of a given element?

Answer (score 2):

It's double/half. So 65 power becomes 130 if rock is targeting scissors, and 32.5 if targeting paper. It might be good to keep a neutral move for some situations, but generally you'd be better off swapping to a different Morty who has the type advantage.